# Changing Visual Studio 2010 Theme

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes

How do I install the .vssettings file I downloaded into VS2010 to "apply" a theme?

Comment: @Kobi - short, sweet, and to the point.  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Tools -> Import And Export Settings...

[alt text http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/keithc/Blog/Lists/Posts/Attachments/16/Tools%20Import%20and%20Export%20Settings%20option.png](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/keithc/Blog/Lists/Posts/Attachments/16/Tools%20Import%20and%20Export%20Settings%20option.png)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Click `Tools`, `Import and Export Settings`, select Import, and click Browse to select the `.VSSettings` file.

I recommend that you backup your current settings first.  (In the second step)